# Issue with Relative/Table Layout

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout, tablelayout

I want the `TextView` to be always on the top of each `EditText`, on all of device's screens. First, I've tried to do something with `RelativeLayout`, but it's not working. Now, I'm trying with `TableLayout`. I would like your opinion for the best layout for this use!

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:stretchColumns="2"
     android:background="@drawable/back" >

     <TextView  android:id="@+id/mathimatika"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:text="Mathimatika Kateuthinsis"
          android:textColor="#09074c"
          android:textSize="14px"
          android:gravity="center" />

     <TableRow>
         <TextView
              android:layout_column="1"
              android:text="Profwrika a"
              android:padding="13dip" 
              android:textColor="#09074c"
              android:textSize="10px"/>
        <TextView
             android:text="Profwrika b"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:textColor="#09074c"
             android:textSize="10px" />

        <TextView
             android:text="grapta"
             android:gravity="right"
             android:padding="13dip" 
             android:textColor="#09074c"
             android:textSize="10px" />
    </TableRow>
    <RelativeLayout>
          <EditText 
              android:id="@+id/input11" 
              android:layout_width="60px"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:textSize="18sp"
              android:numeric="decimal|signed" 
              android:layout_below="@id/vathmos1"
              android:layout_marginLeft="13dip" />

         <EditText 
              android:id="@+id/input21" 
              android:layout_width="60px"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:textSize="18sp"
              android:numeric="decimal|signed"       
              android:layout_toRightOf="@id/input11"
              android:layout_below="@id/vathmos1"
              android:layout_marginLeft="25px" />

        <EditText 
              android:id="@+id/input31" 
              android:layout_width="60px"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:textSize="18sp"
              android:numeric="decimal|signed" 
              android:layout_toRightOf="@id/input21"
              android:layout_below="@id/vathmos1"
              android:layout_marginLeft="25px" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can do it with a `RelativeLayout`, I dont understand why you say you cant do it. But if you want to use it with a `TableLayout`, then you need to have two `TableRow`, one  with the `TextView`s and the other with the `EditText`. Thus, the children of the `TableLayout` will be the `TableRow`s.

However, I would recommend that you use a RelativeLayout, its cheaper because it doesnt have to calculate stuff and its only one level in the stack.

You can define your three `EditText` first, then the three `TextView`s that are above the each `EditText`, and if you want them to be centered, then you can align both the left and the right side to the `EditText`s.
I hope this helps, let me know what you think